# How to obtain User information upon User Task Completion

Tags: jbpm

I am working on a process that requires that an email be sent to all users who completed a task during a process.

My original plan was to add some code into the afterNodeLeft method of my implementation of the ProcessEventListener; however, it seems that the ProcessNodeLeftEvent interface does not have a method for looking up the executing user.

After hitting that dead end, I decided to look at the database tables to what was recorded for history. It appears that the NODEINSTANCELOG tables does not keep track of the user.

As a last ditch attempt, I figured that I could add an output parameter to every user task so that I could add the userid into the results Map. This appears to work, but it feels very kludgey.

Is there some audit service that I could use to look up this information or am I forced to update every user task to track which user completed each task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A human task has an output parameter "ActorId" which you can map to a process variable for usage.  You could also access it (in on-exit scripts or listeners) when you have access to the nodeInstance using:

((HumanTaskNodeInstance) nodeInstance).getWorkItem().getResult("ActorId")

Comment: thanks for the help. I was able to get the NodeInstance from the ProcessNodeLeftEvent parameter of the ProcessEventListener.beforeNodeLeft method. I original placed the code inside the afterNodeLeft, but I found that the afterProcessCompleted was executing before my final afterNodeLeft executed.

Answer (score 2):

yes you can use the task audit mechanism to hook up there the email notifications and keep them completely decoupled from your processes. Look for the TaskEventListener interface. 
HTH

Comment: I am using JBPM 6.1.0.Final. My compiler does not appear to have the TaskEventListener interface loaded and it does not appear in the [JBPM JavaDocs](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.1/javadocs/). Did this interface get removed or renamed?